# Can not load libjli.so in docker container

Tags: java, docker, centos, docker-compose, flyway

I have a ruby app based on docker containers. One of them is a Flyway, building from openjdk:8. Locally (osx sierra) all works perfectly. But when I'm trying to build and launch it on my server, it fails on:

```
flyway_1    | /flyway/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**My environment:**

- CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
- Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
- docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb

**Flyway dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -f -y postgresql-client

COPY ./vendor/flyway/ /flyway
COPY ./db/migrate.sh /flyway
RUN ln -s /flyway/flyway /usr/local/bin/flyway

WORKDIR /flyway
CMD ["bash", "migrate.sh"]
```

I'm a little bit stuck - what can be done to fix that issue?

**UPD 1.**

For some reason, my local flyway container has correctly defined variables for java used by flyway:

```
➜  docker-compose run --no-deps flyway /bin/bash
root@53574d9805a7:/flyway# ldd ./jre/bin/java 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff9bcd2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa9720da000)
    libjli.so => /flyway/./jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so (0x00007fa971ec4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa971cc0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa971922000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563539cb3000)
```

And the identical container deployed to server have no path to libjli.so:

```
➜  sudo docker-compose run --no-deps flyway /bin/bash
root@32d0575719ce:/flyway# ldd ./jre/bin/java 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe24d53000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbb35053000)
    libjli.so => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbb34e4f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbb34ab1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbb35277000)
```

Maybe it's a flyway issue? But why it differs in totally identical containers?

Comment: Did you try to change the image base?. I was reading about this problem and I find some report about it, but they mention only the images based in alpine.

Comment: @German I'm not using alpine and I have tried versions 7, 8 and 9 - all the same stuff. I saw the same discussion on github but it isn't helpful, unfortunately.  The main confusing moment is that on my macbook it builds perfectly from the same source

Comment: Did you try define LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually? 
It's impractical to do that, bue they said that's worked.

Comment: @German, will check it, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is defined on my mac

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH do anything :/

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the answer is simpler than you think it is - flyway always use its own java libs, so if you use autogenerated `.gitignore` file, you need to check if *.so files are not excluded from flyway directory.

I fixed `.gitignore`, pushed a new commit and used it on the server and now it works fine.